# Generate providers for each project in Terragrunt

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

i try to generate providers based on location where I am. Here is the folder structure:

```
src/
├── environments/
│   ├── all/
│   │   └── environment.hcl
│   ├── dev/
│   │   └── environment.hcl
│   ├── test/
│   │   └── environment.hcl
│   └── prod/
│       └── environment.hcl
└── terraform/
    └── infra/
        ├── project1/
        │   ├── main.tf
        │   ├── variables.tf
        │   └── terragrunt.hcl
        ├── project2/
        │   ├── main.tf
        │   ├── variables.tf
        │   └── terragrunt.hcl
        └── terragrunt.hcl
```

My code in `terraform/infra` terragrunt file looks like this:

```
locals {
  wrk_path = trimsuffix(path_relative_to_include(), "/")

  all_path   = "${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/../environments/all"
  all_config = try(read_terragrunt_config("${local.all_path}/environment.hcl").inputs, {})
  env_path   = "${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/../environments/${local.env}"
  env_config = try(read_terragrunt_config("${local.env_path}/environment.hcl").inputs, {})
  fin_config = merge(local.all_config, local.env_config)

  all_var_file = "${local.all_path}/${local.wrk_path}.tfvars"
  env_var_file = "${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/../environments/${local.env}/${local.wrk_path}.tfvars"
}

remote_state {
    // backend
}


terraform {
  // stuff
  }

  extra_arguments "apply_environment" {
    commands = get_terraform_commands_that_need_vars()
    optional_var_files = [
      local.all_var_file, local.env_var_file
    ]
  }
}

inputs = merge(local.fin_config)
```

and then, in `terraform/infra/project1` i want to reference settings from `master` terragrunt hcl and i did a code:

```
include "root" {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

generate "provider" {
  path      = "providers.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite"
  contents = <<EOF
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "abc"
  skip_provider_registration = true
  alias = "${local.fin_config.law}"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "${local.fin_config.sub}"
  skip_provider_registration = true
}
EOF
}
```

But it looks like that config from my master `terragrunt.hcl` is not moved to "local (project1) `terragrunt.hcl`.

My question is, how to read common inputs in master terragrunt hcl file and use it in project's terragrunt.hcl file? Is it possible? if not, what is the best approach? When i place `generate provider` block into my master terragrunthcl `providers` are created in project1 and 2 but i want to have different providers set per project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `local.fin_config` from your master `terragrunt.hcl` to be accessible in each project's `terragrunt.hcl` file.
But, as far as I know, configurations defined in the master file are not automatically available in the child configurations: [Terragrunt](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/) does not natively support the inheritance of locals across configurations.

However, [inputs defined in an included `terragrunt.hcl` file](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/config-blocks-and-attributes/#include) can be accessed by the child configuration. That means you can try and use inputs for shared configuration rather than locals.

Modify your master `terragrunt.hcl` in `terraform/infra` to output `fin_config` as an input that can be inherited by child configurations:

```
# In master terragrunt.hcl
locals {
  # Your locals remain the same
}

inputs = {
  fin_config = local.fin_config
}
```

In your project-specific `terragrunt.hcl` (e.g., within `project1`), you should be able to access `fin_config` through the `inputs` of the included configuration:

```
include "root" {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

generate "provider" {
  path      = "providers.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite"
  contents = <<EOF
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "abc"
  skip_provider_registration = true
  alias = "\${include.root.inputs.fin_config.law}"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "\${include.root.inputs.fin_config.sub}"
  skip_provider_registration = true
}
EOF
}
```

For project-specific configurations (e.g., different Azure subscription IDs), you should define these directly within each project's `terragrunt.hcl` as inputs or manage them through additional `.tfvars` files specified in the `extra_arguments` block.

---

> `Attempt to get attribute from null value`

The error should mean that, when the child configurations try to access `fin_config` via `include.root.inputs.fin_config`, the `fin_config` is not properly initialized or passed down as expected.

Terragrunt's `include` mechanism allows child configurations to inherit `inputs` from parent configurations, but this inheritance does not extend to the `locals` in the same straightforward way. When you try to pass `locals` from the parent configuration to the child through `inputs`, it is important that these `locals` are *fully resolved* and available at the time the child configurations are parsed.

If `fin_config` is dependent on any dynamic values or other `locals` that are not resolved in time, it may result in the child configurations receiving a `null` value when they attempt to access `fin_config` through `include.root.inputs.fin_config`.

A workaround for this issue involves making sure that any values you wish to pass down from the master to the child configurations are not dependent on unresolved `locals`, or are resolved before they are assigned to `inputs`.

The master `terragrunt.hcl` would be (simplified example):

```
# Define a local that you intend to pass down
locals {
  common_config = {
    law = "some-value",
    sub = "another-value"
  }
}

# Directly assign the local value to inputs
inputs = {
  fin_config = local.common_config
}
```

The child `terragrunt.hcl`:

```
include "root" {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

generate "provider" {
  path      = "providers.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite"
  contents = <<EOF
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "abc"
  skip_provider_registration = true
  alias = "\${include.root.inputs.fin_config["law"]}"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "\${include.root.inputs.fin_config["sub"]}"
  skip_provider_registration = true
}
EOF
}
```

So make sure any `locals` used within the `inputs` block of the master configuration are statically defined or resolved early enough to be fully available when the child configurations are processed.
When accessing map attributes in the `contents` of the `generate` block, use the `["key"]` notation to make sure proper interpolation.
Double-check the structure and definitions in your configurations to avoid any timing issues with the evaluation of `locals`.

---

> But, in my master `terragrunt.hcl`, I don't want to use hardcover vars, I want to read vars dynamically.
> That's why I have so many hacks with `fin_config` read from `environment.hcl` files.

So you want to dynamically load configurations from `environment.hcl` files, and use these configurations to generate provider configurations across multiple environments. You need to avoid repetition and keep your Terragrunt configuration DRY (Do not Repeat Yourself).

The challenge becomes to dynamically include environment-specific settings in the Terragrunt configuration for each project without hardcoding variables or repeating code.

A strategy that might work involves leveraging the `locals` block within each project's `terragrunt.hcl` to dynamically read environment configurations while still maintaining a level of DRYness by abstracting common logic into a separate file whenever possible.
Since direct inheritance of `locals` across Terragrunt configurations is not supported, one approach to minimize repetition involves using the `include` block alongside a helper function or script.

So:

- Keep your `environment.hcl` files as they are, centralized under each environment. That will maintain clear, environment-specific configurations.
- Consider abstracting the logic for reading and processing `environment.hcl` files into a separate script or a [Terragrunt `before_hook`](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/hooks/). That script can be invoked to set environment variables or generate a `.tfvars` file that Terragrunt can read from.

  A `load-env-config.sh` script would be:

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash

  # Load environment configurations based on the given environment and set them as environment variables
  # Alternatively, generate a .tfvars file that Terragrunt can consume

  ENV=$1
  CONFIG_PATH="./environments/${ENV}/environment.hcl"

  # Pseudocode: Read the CONFIG_PATH file and export configurations as environment variables
  # or generate a "generated-${ENV}.tfvars" file with the needed variables.

  echo "Variables set for environment: $ENV"
  ```
- In each project's `terragrunt.hcl`, use a combination of `include` to inherit global settings and `locals` to dynamically load environment-specific configurations. If necessary, invoke your abstraction to prepare the environment before Terragrunt runs.

  ```
  terraform {
  # Your Terraform configuration
  }

  before_hook "load_env_config" {
  commands     = ["init", "apply", "plan"]
  execute      = ["bash", "${get_terragrunt_dir()}/load-env-config.sh", "${local.env}"]
  }
  ```
- Dynamically Load Configurations in Project `terragrunt.hcl`:

  ```
  locals {
  # Assuming the environment name is passed via CLI or determined in some way
  env = "dev"
  }

  include "root" {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
  }

  # Use the dynamically set environment variables or read from a generated .tfvars file
  ```

You will need a mechanism to determine the current environment (`dev`, `test`, `prod`, etc.). That could be done through CLI arguments, environment variables, or naming conventions.

Comment: Thank you, will do my best to test your solution!

Comment: Sorry, your code does not work:

terragrunt.hcl:6,21-32: Attempt to get attribute from null value; This value is null, so it does not have any attributes., and 5 other diagnostic(s)
time=2024-03-27T14:44:30+01:00 level=error msg=Unable to determine underlying exit code, so Terragrunt will exit with error code 1

Line 6 is `inputs` block with reference to `fin_config`. How shall i output the fn_config to child modules?

Comment: So i edited my `inputs` to your `inputs` and i pasted `generate providers` block to my child terragrunt.hcl file and it says that values from `${include.root.inputs.fin_config.law}` are null

Comment: Ok now I see your point better. But in my master terragrunt.hcl I don't want to use hardcover vars, I want to read vars dynamically.  That's why I have so many hacks with fin_config read from environment.hcl files

Comment: The whole point is to generate providers dynamically based on environment.hcl as well, not only per project. Then I assume your work will work

Comment: Maybe I should read env.hcl file from project terragrunt.hcl instead of master.hcl? Tried to prevent writing the same code to read env.hcl over and over again

Comment: @michasaucer OK. I have edited the answer to address your last 3 comments.